# React & TypeScript: Functional Components that Are Not Arrow Functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to learn how to use Typescript with react and I understand that I can create the following using typescript:

```
import { FC } from 'react'

interface ChildProps {
  color: string
}

const Child: FC<ChildProps> = ({color}) => {
  return <div>{color}</div>
}
```

What I want to know is how can I do this with a "traditional" function.  I.e., something like this:

```
function Child: FC<ChildProps>({color}) {
  return <div>{color}</div>
}
```

Now, this does NOT work.  I get errors.  For example here is one error that I get:

[image]

What I am wondering is how is it possible to reproduce this using a traditional js function?  If so, how?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React.FC` types a function. That’s in its name, `function component`. Function types are really hard to apply to regularly named functions.

If we don’t type functions, but rather its properties, we can use any form of functions to achieve our goal.

```js
interface ChildProps {
  color: string;
}

function Child({ color }: ChildProps) {
  return <div>{color}</div>;
}
```

Otherwise go with

```js
import { FC } from 'react'

interface ChildProps {
  color: string
}

const Child: FC<ChildProps> = ({color}) => {
  return <div>{color}</div>
}
```

Read more about this subject [here](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react-why-i-dont-use-react-fc/#1.-you-type-a-function%2C-not-its-arguments).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed to know.  If I can just make one suggestion -- I would edit your comment to say that that we CANNOT apply function types to regularly named functions (not that it is hard to do so).  That, at least, is what I understand from the article that you linked to.  Either way, thanks for your help.

Comment: @Moshe Remember that types in TypeScript are [_structural_ and not _nominal_](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-oop.html#erased-structural-types). This means that any value that satisfies some type constraints can be assigned interchangeably. In practice, a function defined `function x(...args: P[]): R { /* ... */ }` can be used where a type of `(...args: P[]) => R` is expected. Using utility types, you can also achieve something similar to arrow function typing: `function x(...args: Parameters<FunctionType>): ReturnType<FunctionType> { /* ... */ }`

Answer (score 0):

You already know what type the parameters to `FC<ChildProps>` are (i.e. `ChildProps`), so you can use that. Although the <s>com</s>transpiler will infer the return type when it is not defined, you can use the [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) utility type to be explicit:

```
function Child({color}: ChildProps): ReturnType<FC<ChildProps>> {
  return <div>{color}</div>;
}
```